# Understanding Scala AnyVal and Null

Tags: scala

Why does the following compile? I understand that AnyVal instances correspond to things in the underlying host system that cannot be constructed, and that Null is a subtype of all reference types but not of value types. I have an AnyVal type Boolean I give to `safeMapDifferent`, but don't see how it can satisfy this constraint of `U >: Null`.

```
object MyMainScala extends App {

  implicit class RichObject[T](o: T) {
    def safeMap[U](method: T => U)(implicit ev: Null <:< U): U =
      Option(o).flatMap(result => Option(method(result))).orNull

    def safeMapDifferent[U >: Null](method: T => U): U =
      Option(o).flatMap(result => Option(method(result))).orNull
  }

  override def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val testSubject = new Object() {
      def scalaBoolean: Boolean = ???
    }

    // println(testSubject.safeMap(_.scalaBoolean)) // If not commented, this will fail to compile as I expect.
    println(testSubject.safeMapDifferent(_.scalaBoolean).getClass) // Why does it compile?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its because of **Autoboxing**. If you see in `predef.scala`, you will see bunch of implicit conversion methods that convert `scala AnyVal` to `Java`.

```
 /** @group conversions-anyval-to-java */
  implicit def boolean2Boolean(x: Boolean): java.lang.Boolean = x.asInstanceOf[java.lang.Boolean]
```

When you invoke your print method, `println(testSubject.safeMapDifferent(_.scalaBoolean).getClass)`, you are providing `T => U` value i.e. `_.scalaBoolean` which takes `testSubject` as parameter which satisfy `T type` parameter and returns `Boolean` which does not satisfy `U >: Null`. Upon getting this error, instead of throwing exception, the compiler looks for `implicit methods` which can convert `Boolean` into expected `U >: Null` type and it found `boolean2Boolean` in `predef.scala` which satisfy this constraint because `java.land.Boolean` is a `reference` type. Hence, compile execute the code correctly.

```
def foo[U >: Null](o : U) = println(o)

foo(true) // compile correctly.
foo[java.lang.Boolean](true) //compile correctly, because true is implicitly converted to java Boolean and java.lang.Boolean is reference type and superType of scala.Null.
```

To avoid this, you must statically provide type parameter: `foo[Boolean](true)  //won't compile.`